# How to add “Refresh” option to right click menu in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, 15.04, nautilus, ppa

I tried to use below steps to add refresh option in Ubuntu 15.04 but getting error

**E: Unable to locate package nautilus-refresh.**

Same steps worked fine in Ubuntu 14.04. Anything I am missing? I am very much new to Ubuntu platform. Thanks

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-refresh
```

Comment: This PPA only contains `nautilus-refresh` for Ubuntu oneiric (11.10) and precise (12.04). You have to find a newer one. (Reference: [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~nae-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=refresh&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=))

Answer (score 0):

This PPA doesn't contain packages for Vivid and later versions of Ubuntu. The latest supported version was Utopic<sup>[1](https://launchpad.net/~nae-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=)</sup>.

The latest version of `nautilus-refresh` was for Precise<sup>[2](https://launchpad.net/~nae-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=refresh&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=)</sup>.